# Using one submit button to Update database and Send email?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I am using one submit button to update data in a database and send an email. However the data is not being saved to the database. The code looks like:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['order_status']))
    {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $orderno =$_POST['order_no'][$i];
    $status =$_POST['order_status'][$i];
    print_r($_POST['order_no']);
    $sql = 'UPDATE Orders SET status="' . $_POST['order_status'] . '" WHERE   Orderno="' .    $_POST['order_no'] . '"';

    mysql_select_db('PurchaseOrders');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
    }
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['order_selected']))
    {
    $keys = array_keys($_POST['order_selected']);

    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        $to = $_POST['order_requested_by'][$key];
        $subject = "Order Form Approval";
        $message = "Your purchase order number: " . " " . $_POST['order_no'][$key] ."    ". "is" ." ". $_POST['order_status'][$key] ;
        $headers = "From: noreply@somewhere.com";
        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;
        if($sent)
        {header( 'Location: http://localhost/test/../' ) ; }
        else
        {print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; }
    }
}
?>
```

In my form the input fields look like this:

```
 echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_supplier['.$i.']" value="' .    $row['Supplier'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_total_price['.$i.']" value="' . $row['totalprice'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_requested_by['.$i.']" value="' . $row['requestedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<select name="order_status['.$i.']" id="id" onchange="showUser(this.value)" >';
    echo '<option value = "Pending"   name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "pending"' . ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Pending</option>';
echo '<option value = "Approved"  name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "approved"' .     ($row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Approved</option>';
    echo '<option value = "Disapproved" name="order_status['.$i.']" class     ="disapproved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Disapproved</option>';
    echo '</select>';
```

I really do not know why this is breaking. When i click submit a message appears that the data has successfully been entered into the database. However no data is entered. Many Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `[$i]` after the POST variable?

Comment: I want to update individual rows in my table based on what select box is checked. I used the same method with a checkbox to send out an email to each person. I can print the contents of the $_POST variable so i know the data I want is being pulled through, I just can't insert it into my database for each specific row. Thankyou

Comment: Could you add the output of printing $_POST to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Im surprised its not throwing an error..

```
echo '<select name="order_status['.$i.']" id="id" onchange="showUser(this.value)" >
```

says

that `$_POST['order_status']` is an array..

So, I would suggest you echo out $sql, and I would imagine you will see why its not updated the record you thought.

Im guessing it should read

```
$sql = 'UPDATE Orders SET status="' .$status  '" WHERE   Orderno="' .$orderno ' . '"';
```

Comment: I understand that however when echoing out the SQL query all I see is an array? and not the data which are in those fields. Thanks

Comment: When you echo $sql as your code stands, yes you would - if you changed it as indicated, looking at the rest of your code, it should work.

Comment: Hi Bugfinder, this example only enters the variable names into the database, and not the content of those variables. Thanks

Comment: No it doesnt... YOUR code put the values of the post variables you wanted, into the 2 variables used, which is why I picked them.. It then inserts the values into the string.. hence its got '.$variable.' it comes out the string concatinates variable contents and goes back into the string

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql Statement has incorrect "/' usage.

Values must be surrounded by ' and not ".

If we strip away your variables in your query YOU have...

```
UPDATE Orders SET status="order_status" WHERE   Orderno="order_no"
```

When  in fact it should be:

```
UPDATE Orders SET status='order_status' WHERE   Orderno='order_no'
```

change your query to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Orders SET status='" . $_POST['order_status'] . "' WHERE   Orderno='" .    $_POST['order_no'] . "'";
```

Comment: I understand that however when echoing out the SQL query all I see is an array? and not the data which are in those fields. Thanks

Comment: Just for giggles, I would make a static query first, then figure out what is in your post variables second.  use var_dump($_POST['order_status']) to find out what the variable is.  If it says it is an array, you'll need to do $_POST['order_status']['name'].

Answer (score 0):

If the $_POST['order_no'] is an array the query will be malformed, this applies to all of the postdata that is an array. That is if you in your html have something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="order_no[]" />
<input type="text" name="order_no[]" />
<input type="text" name="order_no[]" />
```

Then $_POST['order_no'] will have multiple values and your sql-string:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE Orders SET status="' . $_POST['order_status'] . '" WHERE   Orderno="' . $_POST['order_no'] . '"';
```

will not be correct sql.

Comment: it looks like this: echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_no['.$i.']" value="' . $row['Orderno'] . '"/></td>'; I cannot enter the details using variables on insert like: SET status="' .$status

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're getting at, but I would recommend that you echo out the $sql variable so you can see how your query looks like. That should help you debug quite a lot.

Comment: Sorry, when I echo out the contents of the variable I see WHERE Orderno="Array"

Comment: And there's your problem I dare say! Because I have a hard time believing that you want to put that in your db. Try to figure out what you want to get from the array or if you have to rewrite your sql-query.